# Decode emoji from base64 string in java

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, base64

I want to send emoji from javascript to java and then send notification to both Android and IOS app using firebase cloud messaging. I am sending base64 string containing emojis from javascript to java servlet and in servlet when i decode that base64 string got question marks.
Here is my javascript code for encoding message field and sent message to servlet.

```
function sendNotificationToApp(message, startSession)
{
    **message = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( message )))**
    var datastring = "&message="+message;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base+"/SendAppNotification",
        data: datastring,
        dataType: "text",
        cache:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            data    = JSON.parse(data);
            if(data["error"] == null){
                console.log("success")
            }
        },
        error: function(error){
          console.log("error : "+error)
       }
    });
}
```

And Here is my servlet code.

```
String message = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("message"),"UTF-8");
byte[] data = Base64.decode(message, Base64.DEFAULT);
message = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

In message field i got the question marks. Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What’s the encoding of the string before it’s Base64-encoded?

Comment: @Biffen Its simple emoji before Base64-encoded

Comment: If i simply send the emoji on servlet then also get question marks in message field.

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question. What’s the encoding of the string?

Comment: Its message = "Hi " before encoding.

Comment: Still not answering my question, though. Do you know what an encoding is?

Comment: Its my encoded string "SGkg8J+Yg/CfmIPwn5iD"

Comment: So the answer to my question would have been ‘UTF-8’.

Comment: yes its UTF-8 encoded.